# NodeJS MongoDB Recurring Tailable Cursor

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to setup a websocket server with a stream of a tailable cursor. I have a capped collection and have tried using mongo 3.2 and mongo 2.6 to do this so far.

This is the stream I've been trying to get work. It will run once and get all the documents but won't get new documents that I insert. I've seen this code used in countless examples and seen someone stream a chat server but can't seem to get it working for myself.

```
function startStream(){
const stream = collections.MQS.find({}, {tailable:true, awaitdata:true, numberOfRetries:-1}).stream();

stream.on('data', (doc)=>{
   console.log(doc); 
});    
}
```

I call this function in the connection:

```
Mongo.MongoClient.connect (mongodbUri, onConnected);
function onConnected(err, database){
if (err) {throw err;}

// Assign db and collection letiables
collections.db = database;
collections.MQS = database.collection('mqs');

console.log("Connected to: " + mongodbUri);
startStream();
}
```

Is there a more appropriate way to do this that I can't find?

If this query has to be recursive what is the point of having tailable options vs managing time stamps on a normal find query?

Comment: Your code actually works for me. You just need to run it on a capped collection.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not sorting the stream, so I guess you are just tailing the start of the collection: this will not change much unless it reaches the cap of the collection.

Try to add a natural sort in you stream:

```
collections.MQS.find({}, {tailable:true, awaitdata:true, numberOfRetries:-1}).sort({$natural: -1}).stream();
```

Latest syntax from the docs:

```
collections.MQS.find({}).addCursorFlag('tailable', true).stream();
```

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Cursor.html#stream

Comment: Thanks for the comment. When I add sort to the promise chain I get back the error: "MongoError: Tailable cursor doesn't support sorting"

Comment: What is the version of MongoDB used and the version of the driver? @Don

Comment: I'm using driver version 2.1.7 and have used both mongodb 2.6 and 3.2. At this point I've started moving on to AMQP and RabbitMQ as this solution does not appear like it will work.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/jpaljasma/3260eaa6f7a40315863d#file-tailable-cursor-js) is one example shows how to set up `subscriber` function for new MongoDB documents through `cursor`, and print new documents in console.

> ```
> /**
>  * How to subscribe for new MongoDB documents in Node.js using tailable cursor
>  */
>
> // subscriber function
> var subscribe = function(){  
>   var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
>   var next = args.pop();
>   var filter = args.shift() || {};
>
>   if('function' !== typeof next) throw('Callback function not defined');
>
>  // connect to MongoDB
>   require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(err, db){
>
>    // make sure you have created capped collection "messages" on db "test"
>     db.collection('messages', function(err, coll) {
>
>      // seek to latest object
>       var seekCursor = coll.find(filter).sort({$natural: -1}).limit(1);
>       seekCursor.nextObject(function(err, latest) {
>         if (latest) {
>           filter._id = { $gt: latest._id }
>         }
>
>        // set MongoDB cursor options
>         var cursorOptions = {
>           tailable: true,
>           awaitdata: true,
>           numberOfRetries: -1
>         };
>
>        // create stream and listen
>         var stream = coll.find(filter, cursorOptions).sort({$natural: -1}).stream();
>
>        // call the callback
>         stream.on('data', next);
>       });
>     });   
>   });     
> };
>
> // new documents will appear in the console
> subscribe( function(document) {
>   console.log(document);  
> });
> ```

Comment: I've ran into this example before I think. The next callback is bit ambiguous to me but I think this is doing the same thing with the exception of the initial cursor seeking to the last item to setup as a filter. It also appears to have the same error: "MongoError: Tailable cursor doesn't support sorting", as Jonathan's solution.

Comment: @Don, per `.sort` [source code](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/cursor.js.html), please try to change `tailable` to `false`.

Comment: @Don, the `next` is `next = args.pop();` which is `function(document){console.log();}` function passed in...